# How to Find my website Visitor Region Code, IP and City Through simple javascript please no Google Analytics or other Software

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Know how can i find Region of Visitor and IP adress through java script Region and City is on high priority these ones are not working

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#hdnCountryCode").val(geoip_country_code());
        $("#hdnCountyName").val(geoip_country_name());
        $("#hdnCity").val(geoip_city());
        $("#hdnRegionCode").val(geoip_region());
        $("#hdnRegion").val(geoip_region_name());
        $("#hdnLatitude").val(geoip_latitude());
        $("#hdnLongitude").val(geoip_longitude());


      (function(){
       $("#btnV").click();
      return false;
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: i Can use jquery as well

Comment: Are you using any server side language?

Comment: how and where did you defined all those function? (`geoip_country_code` etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That information isn't exposed to JavaScript running in the browser.

You absolutely have to have a service that can:

- See what IP address the user's request comes from (I have 6 IP addresses on this machine, but none of them are likely to be interesting to you as I'm behind NAT)
- Convert data from whatever geo data is available (GeoIP, [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), etc) into the human friendly names you are looking for.

… but since you rule that out in the question, it is simply impossible.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you can do with javascript and HTML5 Geolocation API on newer browser (no IE<9) is a detection of location, latitude and longitude:

see http://html5demos.com/geo and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation

anyway this will require an explicit user permission.